# Why is explorer.exe constantly sending request? Should I be worried?

Tags: windows, networking, internet, windows-explorer

I installed fiddler in Windows and this is what I see when Windows is idle (IE is not running)

[image]

Why is explorer.exe constantly sending requests to google.com and reggistyle.su and also soundcrash.su?

How can I fix this?

Comment: What happens when you disable/uninstall fiddler?

Comment: @DavidPostill How can I know :)

Comment: [tcpview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437)? :/

Answer (score 0):

Foremost explorer.exe is related to Windows Explorer, not Internet Explorer.
Components like Windows search service does use Explorer.exe to communicate with Internet.

Ideally Explorer.exe should not be connecting to internet ;)

Google "disable windows search assistant" to get more info.

Regards ..

Comment: It is already disabled.